# Looking for technical details about X265 encoding and decoding

Tags: c, ffmpeg, java-native-interface, hevc, libx265

I'am working on x265, Is there some one who can you share with me how did I encode yuv using x265 codec? I Need to know how do you get pixel encoded from picture_out structure, And can you tell me if this code is good ? Hope get solution from you! I'am using the x265 api documentation but it is less understandable.

```
ret = x265_encoder_encode(encoder, pp_nal, &pi_nal, pic_in, pic_out);
if(ret < 0){

    printf("encodePictureIn, Error in x265_encoder_encode %d\n",ret);
    return ret; 
}

do{

    ret = x265_encoder_encode(encoder, pp_nal, &pi_nal, NULL, pic_out);
    printf("...\n");

}while(ret > 0);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "get pixel encoded"?

Comment: After calling x265_encoder_encode, I want to retrieve frame which is encoded, is there in pp_nal pointer or in pic_out pointer?   If you have example on how to encode and decode withe x265 codec, please help me. I'am newby in this video streaming.

Comment: x265 doesn't decode. You also cant retrieve a pixel value from an encoded frame without decoding. The documentation is pretty clear. "*pi_nal is the number of NAL units outputted in pp_nal."

Comment: Thank you dear, but I have other questions :

Comment: How do you encode with x265 API, can you share with me some line code ? How to I retrieve encoded data, is there in pp_nal[x].payload fied. Please if it is possible can you share with me som code example.

Comment: pp_nal[x].payload is a pointer to the encoded data. Im not sure what you mean by "retrieve" it. You can memcpy, or write it to a file, or whatever you want.  x265 comes with an example. https://github.com/videolan/x265/blob/master/source/x265.cpp. ffmpeg has one too https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/libx265.c.

Comment: Sorry I am not an english native speaker, by retrieve I mean, how to I save encoded from pp_nal[x].payload to a buffer pointer for example.

Comment: Am I wrong by doing like this ?  for(i=0; i<pi_nal; i++){
  
   memcpy(buffer,pp_nal[i]->payload,pp_nal[i]->sizeBytes);
      buffer += pp_nal[i]->sizeBytes;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Moving from the comment to an answer:

`pp_nal[x].payload` is a pointer to the encoded data. You can memcpy, or write it to a file, or whatever you want. x265 comes with an example. github.com/videolan/x265/blob/master/source/x265.cpp. ffmpeg has one too github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/libavcodec/libx265.c. – szatmary